ffmpeg -f concat won't read file list from command line pipe?
I am trying to use ffmpeg -f concat. It works when I use a temporary file. For tidiness, it'd be nicer to use a piped list. I have seen examples of this in older web postings. Does it no longer work, or am I missing something obvious? Here is a script that illustrates the issue - if you run test.sh x it works by creating a temp file. If you run test.sh then ffmpeg fails. As noted in the script comment, I have tried it with -safe 0 and -protocol_whiteflag "file,pipe,fd".
#!/bin/zsh

o=test.mp4
tmp=test.tmp

if [[ "$1" == "x" ]] ; then
    echo Temp file $tmp...
    ls GX01000?.mp4 | perl -ne 'print "file $_"' > $tmp
    ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -f concat -i $tmp -c copy $o
else
    echo Pipe
    ls GX01000?.mp4 | perl -ne 'print "file $_"' | \
    ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -f concat -i - -c copy $o
    # this command line with -safe 0 and -protocol_whitelist doesn't work either
#   ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -safe 0 -protocol_whitelist "file,pipe,fd" -f concat -i - -c copy $o
fi

Here's the output from the failure case:
% ./test.sh
Pipe
[fd @ 0x6000015f0620] Protocol 'fd' not on whitelist 'crypto,data'!
[concat @ 0x12e7055f0] Impossible to open 'fd:GX010005.mp4'
[in#0 @ 0x6000002f0100] Error opening input: Invalid argument
Error opening input file -.
Error opening input files: Invalid argument

Thanks!

Have you looked at the arguments that end up in the ffmpeg string? It's telling you the arguments you're passing it are wrong, so if you just echo that argument, you will probably find the problem.

What is the point of the ls GX01000?.mp4 | perl -ne 'print "file $_"' > $tmp bit? Parsing the output of ls like that is a bad idea (granted, with the glob you're using it's probably OK, but better to get used to best practice approaches). If you just want to append the string file  to the file name(s) matched by the glob GX01000?.mp4, you could do printf 'file %s\n' GX01000?.mp4 > "$tmp".

This seems to work:
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -safe 0 -f concat \
    -i <(printf "file '%s'\n" "$PWD"/GX01000?.mp4) \
    -c copy "$o"

It's based on @terdon's answer. The critical difference is that the filenames in the file list are now absolute paths, thanks to the $PWD in the glob expression. It also adds single quotes around the names, which are necessary if the full path contains any spaces.
Apparently ffmpeg uses the location of the file passed as the argument to -i as the directory for any relative paths in the list. When you used a temp file, that file was in the same location as the input files, so it worked. When called with a process substitution, ffmpeg saw the filename as something like /dev/fd/12, and assumed all of the relative filenames referred to files in /dev/fd.
This behavior in ffmpeg is, um, unconventional. I have no idea if it is documented anywhere.

Ah ha! That’s it! Thank you.  I would not have thought of relative paths not being relative to the working directory. “Unconventional” is polite. :)

I haven’t had a chance to try it, but wonder if simply prepending ./ to the relative filenames might also work. Will try it later.

Just to follow up, the ./ was still treated as a relative path. Didn’t work. But the absolute paths work great.

Not piping per se, but since your aim is cleanliness, consider subshell file redirection:
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y \
  -f concat \
  -i <(printf "file '%s'\n" "$PWD"/GX01000?.mp4) \
  -c copy $o

<(...) invokes process substitution, which treats the output of a subcommand as a file descriptor ffmpeg can read directly without any special internal logic to switch on the - symbol.
Edit: Updated the original subprocess substitution example with the absolute path trick from Gairfowl.

Ok, tried, and it doesn’t work. I believe the problem is that in ffmpeg’s argument processing scheme the concat module doesn’t get passed the stdin for some reason. Maybe it used to, because I can find references to piping its input via -i - but it no longer does that. I think i just have to live with a temp file.

We may use a named pipe.
Example:
mkfifo list.txt
echo -e "file '/home/rotem/Tmp/input1.mp4'\nfile '/home/rotem/Tmp/input2.mp4'" > list.txt &
ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy output.mp4



mkfifo list.txt - creates a named pipe named "list.txt".
The echo command writes the list of files to the named pipe (using full path).
The echo command ends with & to be executed at the background - required because writing to a named pipe is a "blocking operation".
ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy output.mp4 - reads the list from the named pipe.

At the end, we may delete the named pipe: rm list.txt.

I tested the example with FFmpeg 7.1 in Ubuntu 24.04

Update:
In case anyone stumbles the issue...
According to the accepted answer, using full file path solves the issue.
Using full path is working in Windows terminal:
(echo file /Tmp/input1.mp4 && echo file /Tmp/input2.mp4) | ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -protocol_whitelist file,pipe -i pipe: -c copy output.mp4
In Linux terminal there is still an issue (at least with FFmpeg 7.1):
Executing: echo -e "file /home/rotem/Tmp/input1.mp4\nfile /home/rotem/Tmp/input2.mp4" | ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -protocol_whitelist file,pipe -i pipe: -c copy output.mp4
Gives an error: Impossible to open 'pipe:/home/rotem/Tmp/input1.mp4'
It looks like a bug in FFmpeg...

Interesting, thanks, I will keep that tool in mind. But not sure how it's much different than a simple text file - needs to be created, used, then removed. All do-able, of course, just pipes are tidy when they work. :)

Named pipe is a FIFO, as stdin, but with a name. It is not a persistent file in the disk. It could be considered more tidy than a text file. (I understand that it is not what you were looking for). I don't know why the standard pipe stopped working...

I really doubt using -i - would ever have worked here. The -i option expects a file, not a stream of data, so it needs to be given something that can be treated as a path to a file:

-i url (input)
input file url

However, if your shell is bash or any other that supports process substitution, you could provide the output of the command as a file:
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -f concat -i <(ls GX01000?.mp4 | perl -ne 'print "file $_"') -c copy $o

While you're at it, avoid parsing the output of ls as that is fragile and likely to break (probably not in this case where you have such a simple glob, but better to get used to avoiding it). You should also quote your variables (less essential for zsh, still a good idea). Here's a more robust version of the command:
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -f concat -i <(printf 'file %s\n' GX01000?.mp4) -c copy "$o"


Thanks for the printf tip and the variable quoting link, which I need to learn obviously. But the <(...) trick doesn't work as ffmpeg error results in this (sorry about formatting, still struggling with the comment formatting syntax): [concat @ 0x150805130] Impossible to open '/dev/fd/GX010005.mp4'
[in#0 @ 0x600000bc0100] Error opening input: No such file or directory
Error opening input file /dev/fd/12.
Error opening input files: No such file or directory Somehow ffmpeg is perhaps not chaining the -i argument down into its concat module. I think I'm stuck with simple temp file.

Ah. That's... surprising, @JonCarlson. I don't really have a file handy to test with, I just assumed this would work since it behaves like a file. And zsh should support this, as far as I know.  Could you add the exact command you tried to your question in case there's anything slightly off there and so that others, more knowledgeable than I, might help?
